# What's the most suited types for a list of one keys associated to multiple value

Tags: c#, types

I need to have a list that is something like that : 
MyList
   -Key
       -Multiple values

```
MyList : 
   -1
      -"value1"
      -"value2"
   -2
      -"value2"
      -"value3"
```

It needs to be mutable (changeable after creation) as well.

I've tried multiple type, like a dictionary, with a list as Value like follow

```
Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>();
```

But since key can't be duplicated (even if i don't want them to be, since i add things in this dictionary after a database request, i just want it to add the value to the list if the key already exist) but since there is not insert method for Dictionary, only Add and Remove it seems, and that the order can be changed, it would be a pain to save the state of the key, delete it from the dictionary, add the value to the saved key, and then add it to the dictionary.

I'll detail what i do for now

```
Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>();

if(dictionary.ContainsKey(dataFromBDD.id))
{
    // Add one value at a time to the existant key, but the existant key can have multiple values in it
}
else
{
    // Create the key and add the value
    dictionary.Add(dataFromBDD.id, TheListOfDynamicObject);
}
```

I've also came to LookUp type, but unfortunately it's imutable

So i guessed that maybe there was a type that satisfied what i need, but i've not found anything for now

Comment: If there's a list already there for the key you don't need to add or remove it, just mutate it e.g. `dictionary[key].Add("value4");`.

Comment: From reading your question, I don't get what's wrong with `Dictionary<int, List<dynamic>>`  That seems like the right thing.  To add: First find the right List (or create it if it doesn't exist, then add the item to the list.  To Remove:  Find the right list, remove the item from the list, and optionally, if the list is empty, remove the list from the dictionary.  Can you help me understand your requirement?

Comment: Are you trying to add items one at a time, or are you trying to add a list of multiple items all at once?

Comment: @Wyck I add them one at a time actually, so it confuse me a bit to use a List<dynamic> as value for the dictionary, even if i only have one value to add each time, but each key have multiple value, so how could i not have a List<dynamic> or something similar ? kinda confused here

Comment: Okay, I'll cover both in my answer.  Hopefully not confusing.  Focus on what I wrote for `AddOne` if you just want to add items one at a time.  Obviously you'll need a list though, right?  To see why, consider how you want to **access** this collection.  You supply a key like `2`, now there are multiple items with that key, so the result should be a list of all items added that had that key:  `{ value2, value3 }`, right?  Think of a school: you add a student to a school but put them in a room depending which grade they are in.  The school is the dictionary and the rooms are the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your question if you are trying to add a single item or multiple items all at once.

If you are writing code to add multiple values you can use `AddRange` to add multiple items to a list.  Assuming your incomplete example is intended to use `TheListOfDynamicObject` as an incoming list of dynamic objects to add to the (potentially already existing) list of items already associated with a key, I think it would be dangerous to assign that list to the dictionary because it would get modified when new items get added to the list.  Best not to steal the incoming collection to be used as part of your data structure.

So instead, I would create a special-purposed List for each key, then you can add items to that list as they are added.  You can either add them one at a time, or in batch as a list of items that all share the same key.  Here are two implementations of an `Add` method:

If you are adding many at once:

```
void AddMany(int id, IEnumerable<dynamic> objectsToAdd) {
   // Create an empty list for the given key if it doesn't exist
   if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(id)) {
      dictionary[id] = new List<dynamic>();
   }
   dictionary[id].AddRange(objectsToAdd);
}
```

If you are just adding a single item:

```
void AddOne(int id, dynamic objectToAdd) {
   // Create an empty list for the given key if it doesn't exist
   if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(id)) {
      dictionary[id] = new List<dynamic>();
   }
   dictionary[id].Add(objectToAdd);
}
```

Comment: I've edited here and there and also answered in comments, but yeah should have clarified sooner

Comment: @Luxior Does this answer your question or is there more you need to know?

Comment: Yeah i think i did understand all of it, i'll test more tomorrow, and then close it if it works. Thanks a lot for the explanation !

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
List<Tuple<int, List<dynamic>> list = new List<Tuple<int, List<dynamic>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create(1, new List<dynamic> {"v", "d"}));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(2, new List<dynamic> {"v", "6"}));
```